# Finding exact expression

Tags: trigonometry

Lyndia is flying her kite at the end of a 40-m string. The string makes an angle of (pi/4) with the ground. The wind speed increases, and the kite flies higher until the string makes an angle of (pi/3) with the ground.

a) Determine an exact expression for the horizontal distance that the kite moves between the two positions.

40/cos(pi/4) = 40*root(2)
40/cos(pi/3) = 80
80 - 40*root(2)

b) Determine an exact expression for the vertical distance that the kite moves between the two positions.

40/sin(pi/4) = 40*root(2)
40/sin(pi/3) = 80/root(3)
40*root(2) - 80/root(3)

The answers are wrong... I don't understand.

Comment: Why are you dividing by the cosine and sine of the angles?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a right triangle with two $45^\circ$ angles and a hypotenuse of $40$, the sides will be of length $20$ times the square root of 2, not $40$ times the square root of $2$.

The 30-60-90 right triangle will have side lengths of $20$, $20$ times the square root of $3$, $40$ (the lengths respective to the order of the angles).

[Here's a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTU3Z.jpg)

So, The change in vertical distance would be $\rvert 20\sqrt{2} - 20\sqrt{3}\lvert$.
The change in horizontal distance would be $\rvert 20\sqrt{2} - 20 \lvert$.